# Mount point 0 is not valid path, ignoring and cryptoswap1.swap:8 not an absolute path, ignoring

Tags: boot, encryption, swap, dmesg

I'm using ubuntu 16.04. On startup I started getting a bunch of errors. I have encrypted my disk. When checking `dmesg` I get the following error:

```
Systemd-fstab-generator[44]: Mount point 0 is not a valid path,ignoring
System[1] /run/systemd/generator/dev-mapper-cryptoswap1:swap:8 not an absolute path, ignoring: /dev/mapper/cryptswap1
```

- Can someone please explain what this means?
- How could this happen?
- I have few applications on my system and rarely make changes.

I'll also add some other errors that happening during the dmesg in case they are related lpc_ich: resource conflicts found affecting gpio_ich, and also this errors: ACLU error: field d128 at 1040 exceeds buffer, powercap intel-rail:0: package locked by bios, monitoring only

- Also, could this be the result of system crack?
- How can I restore this without wiping my system?
- Can I restore the right path?
- How do I prevent this from happening again?

Here is /etc/fstab:

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
    #
    # Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
    # device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
    # that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
    #
    # <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
    /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro     0       1
    # /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
    UUID=c46b918d-5399-42d7-b8ce-dc35a17109b2 /boot           ext2     defaults     $
    #/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
    dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
    tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs
    defaults,noexec/nosuid  0 0
    none /run/shm tmpfs  defaults, ro 0 0
```

Comment: I'll also add some other errors in case they are related lpc_ich: resource conflicts found affecting gpio_ich, and also this errors: ACLU error: field d128 at 1040 exceeds buffer,  powercap intel-rail:0: package locked by bios, monitoring only

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Please show your `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Hi, @AlexP - thanks , here it is (removed comments to make space):
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=c46b918d-5399-42d7-b8ce-dc35a17109b2 /boot           ext2    defaults     $
#/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
tmpfs /run/shm tmpfs
defaults,noexec/nosuid  0 0
none /run/shm tmpfs  defaults, ro 0 0

Comment: Please post it in the question as a code block. As far as I can tell you have a syntax error on the line mounting `/boot` (the last token is `$` which AFAIK is not allowed); you have a syntax error on the line for swap (it does not start with a `/`).

Comment: Hi @AlexP I realised as soon as I posted that it looks bad so I added it to the question by edit and hopefully this is much for readable - thanks for reviewing this!

Comment: Your `fstab` is malformed. See previous comment.

Comment: @AlexP thanks, I added a / at the start of the lin with /dev. Can't see the $ sigh so left that one. Rebooted and now i get; Failed to create mount unit file /run/systemd/generator/run-shm.mount, as it already exists. Duplicate entry in /etc/fstab

Comment: @AlexP, if you add your comment as an answer I can close this and award. i've looked up the latest issue and it seems like it not a big deal so I'm going to leave it for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you have a syntax error in `/etc/fstab` on the line mounting `/boot` (the last token is `$` which AFAIK is not allowed); and you have a syntax error on the line for swap (it does not start with a `/`).

Answer (score 1):

Check your `/etc/fstab` file with this command:

```
findmnt --verify
```

This will check your `fstab` for errors and ensure that the mount devices are accessible.

Specifically, `Systemd-fstab-generator[44]: Mount point 0 is not a valid path,ignoring` might mean that there is an extra line break or some extra white space in a line in your `fstab` (although based on the `fstab` listed above, it looks like the `$` is the problem). Replacing all of the whitespace with spaces helped me fix this in my config.

The `findmnt` warning `[W] cannot detect on-disk filesystem type` will disappear with `sudo`. You can get more information with the option `--verbose`.